# Data to another page

Tags: javascript, html

I’m trying to have an input on one page where, let’s say, the user puts their name in, and then on clicking the submit button it takes them to another page where it says Hello “name”.

I seem to have it working, but then when I tried another page it doesn't carry the input over.

Is there a way to do this all on one page? I don’t want the output showing. If it's one page I want to make a transition so it's like a full screen input name: then submit transition into a new screen with Hello, “name”.

Code I have so far:

```
<label>Type your name: </label>
<input type="text" id="txtName">
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="transfer()">

<script>
function sayHi(){
  var txtName = document.getElementById("txtName");
  var txtOutput = document.getElementById("txtOutput");
  var name = txtName.value;
  txtOutput.value = "Hi there, " + name + "!";
}

function transfer() {
  location.href = "output.html";
}
</script>
```

New page

```
<input id="txtOutput">
```

Comment: Where do you call "sayHi"? Where do you pass the name? You need something like  `location.href = "output.html?name="+encodeURIComponent(name);` and a script on the other page to grab the passed name.

Comment: the web is _stateless_. Nothing is preserved going from one page to another (or even a refresh of the same page) unless you explicitly make that happen. Right now you just transfer to the next page (using location.href) and everything you did on this one...well it might as well never have happened. It ceases to exist as soon as you navigate away from it. You should probably learn about form submission, querystring parameters and (optionally) server-side scripting as well

Comment: Did not know the first part and ya i know a bit of php but this site i can’t use server side stuff.

Comment: If you have one page, then have the second part display:none and show it when you have the name

Comment: that's a good point, instead of refreshing you could just do it all in one page by showing/hiding parts of the page using JavaScript

Comment: That’s what my original thought was. I’m trying to think how i can set that up exactly cause if i was gonna do that i would want a transition to go with it to look nice

Comment: well you can do stuff with CSS or Javascript to do that, you can google examples, and libraries like jQueryUI (and others) provide some ready made animation functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in the [localstorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Localstorage allows you to store data in the browser like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('item1', 'value1');
```

You can access later like this data later like this:

```
let cat = localStorage.getItem("item1");
```

Comment: Will check this out.

Comment: Or you could also use cookies if you want to support IE < 8 :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to send value in page 1 to Page 2. In your case you are execute script in Page 1 and taking the user to Page 2 where the entire page loads again. Your executed script is gone.

Your Page1.html

```
<label>Type your name: </label>
<input type="text" id="txtName">
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="transfer()">
<script>
function transfer() {
    location.href = "output.html?name="+document.getElementById("txtName").value;
}
</script>
```

Now, your user will be taken to output.html?name={name he had entered}

output.html:

```
<input id="txtOutput">
<script>
// function to get data from URL.
function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
var result = null,
    tmp = [];
var items = location.search.substr(1).split("&");
for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
    tmp = items[index].split("=");
    if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
}
return result;
}

document.getElementById("txtOutput").value = "Hi "+findGetParameter("name");
</script>
```

Please let me know if it was helpful. However, I would suggest you to understand how back_end technologies work. and look at local storage.

Comment: This worked besides when it outputs it says null and not the name.